# How to do a proper JOIN logic between 2 tables

Tags: sql, join

Rather new to SQL.

I have 2 tables where I need to create an appropriate join between them.  Tables: Table1 and Table2.
Table1 has the following columns: Domain, Instance, Project, and Upload.
Table2 has the following columns: Domain, Instance, Project Derivation, Upload, and ID.

Ultimately I want to bring the ID column from Table2 into Table1.  However, Project and Project Derivation are not an exact match.  Rather the value of Project will be found somewhere in Project Derivation.

My thinking is the following:

```
Table1.Domain=Table2.Domain
Table1.Instance=Table2.Domain
Table1.Upload=Table2.Upload
```

Table1.Project is in Table2.Project Derivation

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Table 1** 
[image: Table1]

---

**Table 2** 
[image: Table2]

Comment: Can we please see some of the data for those tables?

Comment: post your table structures

Comment: Maybe it would help understand, if you didn't call the tables table1 and table2, but tell us the real names, so we get an idea what they actually contain.

Answer (score 0):

The join would include `LIKE`, so as to compare

```
WHERE 'Cloud, Cloud - Config' LIKE '%Cloud - Con%'
```

The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON  t2.domain = t1.domain
        AND t2.instance = t1.instance
        AND t2.project_derivation like '%' || t1.project || '%';
```

However, you would also find entries for a project `'Better Plans'` when looking for a project called `'Bet'` or `'Plan'`. This is because your table design is not good. You are not using the relational database system properly. If parts of a string are of interest to your query, then store the parts separately.

Without knowing much of your data, I'd suggest in your case to have a `project_derivation` table containing one record per project derivation along with the related project. Then you would no longer be interested in substrings, but merely find the link from project derivation to project in this table.

There may be more flaws in your database design. Why do both tables share domain and instance? Does a project only have a meaning within the two (i.e. there can be a project Audit for Google.com/Dev and quite another project with the same name for Ebay.com/Dev)? This may be okay and you'd have a composite key then, but maybe you are merely storing data redundantly.